# Is this a sublattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, relations

I had a question in a previous year paper of discrete maths. It asked-
"Determine all the sub-lattices of D30 that contain at least four elements,
               D30={1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30}.
"
I came up with the following hasse diagram:

[image: hasse diagram]

The hasse diagram looks like a cube projected in 2D and from what I understand, every face of this cube should be a valid sublattice with atleast 4 elements, what other sublattices exist with 4 or more elements?
And another aside question, is {1,2,3,6} a valid sublattice in this case, because i think it is but the answer key says otherwise. A photo of answer key is also attached. But I think there is something wrong with this answer key altogether because it does not list the whole lattice itself (i.e. all the elements of lattice) as a valid sublattice having greater than 4 elements. I am not good at discrete maths. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer Key:
[image: answer key]

Comment: You're right, the full lattice is missing from the list. If you take a fifth element to a face, they will generate the whole lattice.

Comment: Yes, can you clear up my theory of each face being a valid sublattice? Is {1,2,3,6} a valid sublattice?

Comment: $\{1,2,3,30\}$ is not a sublattice, as $2\vee 3=6\notin\{1,2,3,30\}$. Not only are things missing,  (2) is not a sublattice.

Comment: The answer key seems wrong in more perspectives. Well, for me, 'sublattice' would mean that it's closed under the original $\land,\lor$ operations, so e.g. $\{1,2,3,6\}$ is but $\{1,2,3,30\}$ is not a sublattice. Btw, my previous statement was false, for example $\{1,2,3,6,30\}$ is also a valid sublattice. Nevertheless, we could losen up a bit the meaning of 'sublattice' to be a subset such that the inherited poset structure becomes a lattice, in that sense $\{1,2,3,30\}$ works, but then we have even more sublattices.

Comment: @Arturo , but 6 is not there in 1,2,3,30... I don't think the 2v3 value is 6 anymore... It should be 30 now

Comment: @Vaibhav: That’s our point: a sublattice should be a subset that is closed under the original operations. The original operation gives $2\vee 3=6$, so $6$ should be in the set... and it isn’t. If you want to define “sublattice” as “subset which is a lattice under the induced partial order” then (i) that’s, IMHO, the wrong definition from the algebraic point of view; and (ii) then you are missing a heck of a lot more “sublattices” in the list.

Comment: For example, $\{1,2,3,5,30\}$ should also be a “sublattice”, as should would be $\{1,2,3,10,30\}$, etc.

Comment: So you're saying that we should compare with the initial value only as not considering this constraint will make almost any set of points a lattice? It seems that your definition is more restrictive and correct... But who knows for sure? What do the top books in this subject have to say?

Comment: Most books I am familiar define a sublattice of $L$ as a subset $M$ of $L$ such that if $a,b\in M$, then $a\vee b$ and $a\wedge b$ are both in $M$, with join and meet computed in $L$. That’s the way to define it from the algebraic point of view. It’s possible to define sublattice as a subset that happens to be a lattice under the induced order. I do not know what definition you guys were using. But whichever definition you were using, the answer is wrong (though for different reasons, depending on the definition).

Comment: Note that I wasn’t in your course, **you** were. So you should know what definition of “sublattice” you were using.

Comment: Well I dug into the course material and according to them comparison should be done with respect to the original values and only if the old meet and join are there in the set for each pair, only then its a sublattice ...@Arturo is right... You can go ahead and answer it if you want mate...